# Why can't I pass a `func() []int` as `func() []interface{}` in go?

Tags: go, interface

I have the following definition:

```
func (c *Collector) RegisterSource(f func() []interface{}) {
    c.source = f
}
```

I attempt to call it as follows but get an error:

```
func source() []int {
    return []int{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
}
...
c.RegisterSource(source)
```

This is met with:

```
cannot use source (type func() []int) as type func() []interface {} in argument to c.RegisterSource
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but anyway this should help: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice

Comment: For the obvious reason that they are different types.

Comment: From the Go FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [relevant Go FAQ entry](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) states that `[]T` and `[]interface{}` «do not have the same representation in memory».

To understand why, let's dissect two things:

1. A slice is a backing storage [array](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) plus several integers containing the size and capacity
   of the slice.

   In Go, arrays are not somehow "high-level"; on the contrary,
   the layout of the elements they contain is strictly defined: they are all
   contained in a contiguous region of memory, adjacent to each other.

   This means, that in the backing array of a slice `[]T`, elements are of
   type `T`, and each of them occupies a region of memory of a size natural
   for that type `T`, and all these regions are all adjacent to each other
   in a single contiguous memory block.

   That means, each element of a slice `[]int` occupies exactly 64 bits
   (8 bytes) on a 64-bit platform — the amount of memory a single `int` value
   occupies.
2. A value of any interface type, including the empty interface,
   `interface{}`, is represented as a structure containing two pointers,
   something like:

   ```
   type iface struct {
       realType  *typeInfo
       realValue *dataType
   }
   ```

   (More on how interfaces are represented — [here](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)).

All of the above means in a slice `[]interface{}` each element occupies the
region of memory the size of two pointers, and these two pointers contain
addresses of other variables in memory — as opposed to mere integer values
contained by elements of `[]int`.

And this, in turn, means you can't just "cast" `[]int` "to" `[]interface{}` — simply because a value stored in any element of `[]int` (an `int`) is
incompatible in its structure (memory layout) with an element
of `[]interface{}` (a struct containing two pointers).
To produce one from another, you need to allocate a slice and convert each
element of the source slice to a matching element of the destination one.

Finally, this means if a function returns a slice of type `[]int`,
that slice cannot be directly processed by code expecting slices of
type `[]interface{}` (and vice-versa), and this explains why
the two function signatures from your question represent incompatible
types.

Answer (score 2):

Because []int and []interface are 2 different types of slices and go does not allow automatic conversion between the 2.

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice

all you can do is change this

```
func source() []int {
    return []int{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
}
```

into that

```
func source() []interface{} {
    return []interface{}{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
}
```

in order to fit the function signature you defined for `RegisterSource`.